# Add custom command with custom counter to table of contents

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

I defined a `new command` so that I can get the `enumeration` of the `subsections` with the format that I want. Now my problem is that I don´t know how to make these numbers and its respective title appear on the table of contents (`\tableofcontents`).

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{ulem}  

\begin{document}  
\tableofcontents  
\newcounter{UntUntKap}[section]  
\newcommand{\nummeriere}[1]{\stepcounter{UntUntKap}\uline{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{UntUntKap}} \ #1}  
\section{erste}  
\nummeriere{ das ist text } \\  
\nummeriere \\  
\nummeriere\\  
\nummeriere  

\end{document}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I tried with `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{*}` , but either i am using it wrong or this command doesn´t accept my "`\nummeriere`" in it. My optimal scenario would be that the "`add to toc`" were included in my custom command, but if i have to write it every time i can also create a simpler command I guess...

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to change the formatting of sections both in the main text and in the table of contents, the packages [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and [titletoc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) might be of interest to you.

---

In case you wish to do "by hand", without these packages:

The usual hierarchy of sectioning-counters below `chapter` is:

`section` → `subsection` → `subsubsection` → `paragraph` → `subparagraph`.

The corresponding sectionig-commands are:

`\section` → `\subsection` → `\subsubsection` → `\paragraph` → `\subparagraph`.

All these things denote sections. 
"subsection", "subsubsection", "paragraph"  etc is just LaTeX-jargon for denoting different levels of sectioning.

Your counter `UntUntKap` denotes the same level of sectioning as the `subsection`-counter.

So instead of defining a `\nummeriere`-command which is connected to a numbering-infrastructure which is parallel to the numbering-infrastructure connected to the `\subsection`-command I would probably define my own customized variant of the `\subsection`-command which uses the same numbering-infrastructure as the `\subsection`-command.

Be that as it may.

You can implement a numbering-infrastructure parallel to the numbering-infrastructure connected to the `\subsection`-command as follows:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ulem}  

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2} % 1 -> sections are the last sectioning-level that gets numbered.
                            % 2 -> subsections are the last sectioning-level that gets numbered.
                            % 3 -> subsubsections are the last sectioning-level that gets numbered.
                            % etc

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} % 1 -> sections go to toc
                         % 2 -> sections and subsections go to toc
                         % 3 -> sections, subsections and subsubsections go to toc
                         % etc

\newcounter{UntUntKap}[section]  
\renewcommand\theUntUntKap{\thesection.\arabic{UntUntKap}}%

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\l@UntUntKap=\l@subsection}%
\newcommand\CheckWhetherArgumentIsEmpty[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \ifcat A\detokenize{#1}A%
    \@firstoftwo{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}{} %
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \@firstoftwo{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}{} %
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}%
\newcommand\nummeriere{%
  \@ifstar\nummeriere@star\nummeriere@nostar
}%
\newcommand{\nummeriere@star}[1][]{%
  #1\@bsphack\@esphack
}%
\newcommand{\nummeriere@nostar}[1][]{%
  \ifnum 2>\c@secnumdepth\else
    \refstepcounter{UntUntKap}%
    \underline{\theUntUntKap}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{UntUntKap}{%
      \ifnum2>\c@secnumdepth\else
        \protect\numberline{\theUntUntKap}%
      \fi
      \CheckWhetherArgumentIsEmpty{#1}{\protect\kern-.6em}{#1}%
    }%
    \space
  \fi
  #1%
  \@bsphack\@esphack
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}  
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{A chapter}
\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}%
\section{A section whose hierarchy-level is named ``section'' in \LaTeX-jargon.}
\subsection{A section whose hierarchy-level is named ``subsection'' in \LaTeX-jargon.}
\nummeriere[This is text belonging to a numbering-structure, not really a sectioning-structure,
            which is parallel to the numbering of subsections that goes to the toc as well.]
            This is text belonging to a numbering-structure, not really a sectioning-structure,
            which is parallel to the numbering of subsections that does not go to the toc.\\  
\nummeriere This is text belonging to a numbering-structure, not really a sectioning-structure,
            which is parallel to the numbering of subsections that does not go to the toc.

\nummeriere This is text belonging to a numbering-structure, not really a sectioning-structure,
            which is parallel to the numbering of subsections that does not go to the toc. %%%
\nummeriere This is text belonging to a numbering-structure, not really a sectioning-structure,
            which is parallel to the numbering of subsections that does not go to the toc.\

\bigskip

Having two parallel numbering-structures, namely the numbering-structure that belongs to sections
whose hierarchy-level is named ``subsection'' in \LaTeX-jargon and the numbering-structure that
underlies the \verb|\nummeriere|-command is confusing.

Unless you never use them parallel throughout the whole document.

I.e.:

\begingroup\sloppy
When you have two consecutive \verb|\section|s with  \verb|\subsection|s/\allowbreak\verb|\subsubsection|s/\allowbreak etc
in between, then there should not also be \verb|\nummeriere| in between.

When you have two consecutive \verb|\section|s with  \verb|\nummeriere| in between, then
there should not also be  \verb|\subsection|s/\allowbreak\verb|\subsubsection|s/\allowbreak etc in between.

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]